# for each cell vba

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

Everytime I'm trying to do a for each cell within a specified column I get an error. I understand more and more vba but not the loop method it seems.

Here's my code:

```
Sheets("DB").Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.AutoFilter
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
' ************** Si le systeme a planté *******************
'''''''  ' filtre le IN USE
Sheets("Search Criteria").Range("O2").Value = "In Use"
'filter Locked by who based on the USER ID in DB
        Dim Usedd As Range
        Dim InUse As Range
        Set Usedd = Sheets("Search Criteria").Range("O2")
        Set InUse = Sheets("DB").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        With InUse
            If Usedd.Value <> "" Then
                Sheets("DB").Select
                .AutoFilter field:=11, Criteria1:=Usedd.Value, Operator:=xlOr
            End If
        End With
'if IN USE then verify if there is an empty line that is reservecd but with no user id
Dim cell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
For Each cell In Sheets("DB").Range("BP2:BP" & LastRow)
    If cell.Value = "" And cell.Offset(0, -58).Value = "In Use" Then
        cell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next cell

' ************** Fin de si le systeme a planté
Selection.AutoFilter
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("DB").Range("K1048576").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.Value = "In Use"
    Selection.Offset(0, -1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value + 1
```

The error I get is object not define.
I can't seem to see what is not define in my code.
Basically what I want to do is to look in column BP. If the client user id is found look at column K and if column K has on that row In Use then delete this row.

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: Whats the value of LastRow?    Also, you'll need to reference cell I think in the delete as you'll just keep deleting the active row.  So `cell.entirerow.delete`

Comment: Deleting while looping is frequently problematic. If you must do that -- loop from bottom to top rather than vice versa. In any event, why not include enough code so as you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: thanks everyone I have made the changes like mentioned below and above, declare my variable and change the active cell delete to cell delete. However I still get the application define or object define error. I will add more cod as suggested by @JohnColeman. I have also removed the Goto since infact I do not need it.

Comment: You don't give `LastRow` a value...

Comment: What does that mean @Marcucciboy2? I'm still new to vba and don't know how to use lastrow. For me it just made sense to use lastrow since going through the entire column will mean it will look through the last row of the database. The lastrow is, at least in my case, unknown since the database is growing every time a client enters data. how would I make LastRow dynamic?

Comment: @ValS please see my answer below, I get the value for LastRow before using it.

Comment: Just creating the variable `LastRow` is a good start, but you have to tell VBA what the actual number the last row is, it's not a built-in function https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Answer (score 2):

Since you are looping on your `cell` range object, replace:

```
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
```

With

```
cell.EntireRow.Delete
```

Don't forget to declare all your variables, such as:

```
Dim cell As Range, Dim LastRow As Long
```

Answer (score 2):

I would loop backwards when deleting rows, also define your variables appropriately, the reason for your error as Marcucciboy2 mentions is that your LastRow variable is never initialized:

```
Dim counter As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DB")
'declare and set your variables above

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "BP").End(xlUp).Row
'get the Last row with data in column BP to use in the following For Loop

For counter = LastRow To 2 Step -1 'loop from last row to the second row
    If ws.Cells(counter, "BP").Value = "" And ws.Cells(counter, "K").Value = "In Use" Then
        ws.Rows(counter).Delete
        'GoTo Pas_plante
    End If
Next counter
```

Comment: if you use .rows() you don't need .entirerow before .delete.   Just ws.Rows(counter).Delete is sufficient.  Had you used cells, you would use cells(counter,col).entirerow.delete

Comment: @Xabier I would not reference a worksheet like `Set ws = Sheets("DB")` because you have not referenced it from the workbook you're working with like this `Set ws = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DB")`.

Comment: Thanks updated my answer to reflect your comments, but will leave my answer as it might be helpful for someone else. :)